# How to merge results of two unrelated xpath queries?

Tags: java, xpath, merge, aem, jcr

I have two xpath queries

`query1` and `query2`

result of execution query1 is

```
row11
row12
```

result of execution query2 is

```
row21
row22
row23
row24
```

I want to write **single** query with following result:

```
row11
row12
row21
row22
row23
row24
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Do you have to use XPath? If you can transform your query to be built using [`Predicate.class`](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/search/Predicate.html) you could add two queries to one PredicateGroup with `setAllRequired(false)` specified.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply have `List` of rows where you add the result of both queries. If both results can have the same rows you would have to define an identifier and use a `Map` with this id as the key.

Example with simple `List`:

```
QueryManager qm = session.getWorkspace().getQueryManager();
Query q1 = qm.createQuery(statement1, "xpath");
QueryResult r1 = q1.execute();
RowIterator rows1 = r1.getRows();

Query q2 = qm.createQuery(statement2, "xpath");
QueryResult r2 = q2.execute();
RowIterator rows2 = r2.getRows();

List<Row> rowsMerged = new ArrayList<Row>();
while (rows1.hasNext()) {
 rowsMerged.add(rows1.nextRow());
}
while (rows2.hasNext()) {
 rowsMerged.add(rows2.nextRow());
}
```

Comment: This is a bit overhead. Could I write something like query1 and query2 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using XPath union (`|`) operator. For example, given this XML :

```
<Employee>
    <EmpId>1</EmpId>
    <Name>Sam</Name>
    <Sex>Male</Sex>
</Employee>
```

And this XPath which contains union operator :

```
(/Employee/EmpId | /Employee/Name)
```

Output nodes in XPath tester :

```
<EmpId>1</EmpId>
<Name>Sam</Name>
```

Comment: try to wrap both queries within brackets, like : `(query1 | query2)`. Or maybe this XPath syntax isn't supported if you still get syntax error...

Comment: looks like not supported